# Dynamically causing the div to expand on a href click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically expand a div based on an anchor link click. The anchor link, `view comments` will expand and display user comments based on the click on the link.

I have a database with the following two relevant tables:

```
user_thoughts
  id
  message
  added_by
```

and ...

```
user_comments
  id
  body_of_msg
  comment_posted_by
  comment_posted_to
  post_id
```

I have the following queries:

```
$get_thoughts_from_db = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_thoughts WHERE added_by='$user' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_thoughts_from_db)) {
    $thought_id      = $row['id'];
    $message_content = $row['message'];
    $thoughts_by     = $row['added_by'];
```

and another to obtain data from the user_comments table...

```
// Get the comments attahed to a users post...
$get_comm = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_comments WHERE post_id='$thought_id' ORDER BY post_id DESC");
$comment = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($get_comm);
    $comment_body           = $comment['body_of_msg'];
    $comment_posted_to      = $comment['comment_posted_to'];
    $comment_posted_by      = $comment['comment_posted_by'];
    $removed                = $comment['comment_removed'];
```

Each thought by a user is echo'd, but when I press `view comments`, it does not load the comment in the div.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function toggle <?php echo $thought_id ?>() {
        var ele = document.getElementById("toggleComment <?php echo $thought_id ?>");
        var text = document.getElementById("displayComment <?php echo $thought_id ?>");
        if (ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                ele.style.display = "block";
                }
        }
</script>
```

And here is where the comments and the link are made...

```
<div class='mini_nav' style='float: right;'>
                                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty' data-clicked='false' aria-hidden='true'></span> 
                                <span style='padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;'> | </span>
                                <a href='#' onClick='javascript:toggle$thought_id()'> View comments </a> 
                            <div id='toggleComment$thought_id' style='display:none;'>
                                <br/> $message_content
                            </div>
```

I fully expect my javascript to work but it just doesn't load the comments with the same post_id as the thought_id.

Comment: You are building a function for every element?

Comment: `toggle <?php echo $thought_id ?>()` is not going to create a valid function name. need to at least remove the space.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the JS function like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function toggle(id) {
        var ele = document.getElementById("toggleComment" + id);
        if (ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

And define your html:

```
<div class='mini_nav' style='float: right;'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty' data-clicked='false' aria-hidden='true'></span>
    <span style='padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;'> | </span>
    <a href='#' onclick='toggle($thought_id)'> View comments </a>
    <div id='toggleComment$thought_id' style='display:none;'>
        <br/> $message_content
    </div>
</div>
```